# Why can phosphorus have 5 bonds while nitrogen cannot?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Phosphorus can form 5 bonds like in the case of phosphate. While nitrogen is known to make a maximum of 4 bonds (3 covalent, 1 dative covalent). But why is this so?

Is it because nitrogen *doesn't have* available d orbitals while phosphorus  *has* available d orbitals? Or does the presence of d orbitals have nothing to do with this and it's the sizes of both atoms that allows them to make more bonds?

Comment: This is a complex subject, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervalent_molecule and http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00178a014

Comment: They (and all the other elements) have "available" *d* (and higher) orbitals - whether they're occupied is another matter.

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42750/how-can-the-size-of-atom-be-the-cause-of-octet-expansion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't NH5 form?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/100911/why-cant-nh5-form)